# Odd Cygwin issue when having an alias in my .inputrc file

Tags: bash, cygwin

When adding some aliass to .inputrc I noticed my 'a' key wasn't working on my keyboard when using Cygwin Bash.  Took out all my alias and my 'a' key started working again.  For testing I stripped down my .inputrc to look like this:

```
alias foo='ls' 
set bell-style none
```

Here is what I noticed

- If I type 'foo' at command prompt I get 'bash: foo: command not
  found'
- I also can't type 'a' without a beep.
- I also don't get any beeping so 'set bell-style none' was set.

If I take out 'set bell-style none' here is what I noticed:

- My system beeps when I press 'a' but 'a' doesn't show on screen.
- If I type 'foo' at command prompt I get 'bash: foo: command not
  found'
- My system beeps.

If I take out "alias foo='ls'" here is what I noticed:

- Pressing 'a' works.
- Everything else works as normal.
- If I type in "alias foo='ls'" and type "foo" I get a list of directories.

I went looking for some type of logged error but couldn't find anything.

Thanks,
   Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`inputrc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html) file control readline whereas `~/.bashrc` is executed by bash. You should keep `set bell-style none` in `~/.inputrc` and place `alias foo='ls'` in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: It might be worth explaining what the `alias` line was actually causing Readline to do, and hence the beeps.

Comment: I really have no idea, as `alias foo='ls'` is completely incorrect syntax. I presume (unless disabled by a previous configuration setting) that readline would ring the bell in an attempt to warn the user when it encounters (attempts to execute) an incorrect key binding.

Comment: It's incorrect syntax that gets treated as a binding for the character that is the first letter of the word "alias", because Readline's configuration file parser has some poor error checking.  (-: